# Get Preferent Path and All Nodes of Preferent Path in Cooja for RPL

Tags: c, iot, contiki, cooja, contiki-process

I'm using Cooja simulator to study RPL protocol and I'm trying to implement some studies that done already. I must check whether this implementation is correct or not. For this checking, I want to get all nodes of path in Contiki Cooja for RPL in rpl-mrhof.c file.
How can I get these ?

Comment: Impossible, if I understand what you mean by "preferent path". There is not such information kept by the RPL protocol.

Comment: I mean that we can calculate path metric with calculate_path_metric(rpl_parent_t *p) function in rpl-mrhof.c file. I want to get nodes of this path.@kfx

Comment: Well, you can't. RPL does not have this information. It's a distance vector protocol. Also, please edit your question so that it uses standard terms and please show that you have done some research when asking questions!

Comment: Thank you so much! But you know, RPL sent packet from source node to destination node. Then, how RPL sent this packet ? I think RPL know which nodes are used when the packet is sent. Am ı wrong ? @ kfx